# drupal 7 flex slider cycle doesn't work until I open page inspector

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-views, flexslider, jquery-cycle

I have an odd scenario happening on a production site for Arcade Brewery.

I am using flex slider for a responsive slide show on the home page and the beers page.
They are served with views and Flex Slider Views Slideshow.
They worked fine for months. Recently, they stopped sliding. 
It still rotates through the images, if I switch settings to fade, that works fine, just not horizontal slide.
I've not been able to trace back to when they did work.

If I open web inspector in Safari and/or Chrome and click on the UL element style, it suddenly starts working (as if it realizes I'm investigating! ha).

Anyone else seen this? What could cause this behavior?

thanks!
jason

Comment: Found the problem. There were clashes with CSS3 effects. Checked "Video" under advanced setting in the UI. That turned off CSS3 3D Transforms, and fixed my problem. Turning off "Use CSS" also fixes the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are clashes with CSS3 effects. Checked "Video" under advanced setting in the UI. That turned off CSS3 3D Transforms, and fixed my problem. Turning off "Use CSS" also fixes the issue...